# SwiftUI & Contentful Client Error: Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

Tags: arrays, xcode, swiftui, contentful, contentful-api

The code below shows the code I am using to fetch data from Contentful API to my SwiftUI app. However, by calling the function `client.fetchArray`, I got an error message saying that the type of expression is ambiguous. I tried look up the documentation and the example code for `client.fetchArray` uses the exact parameters and hence I assume the error message should be gone? Can anyone please help me out here! I am super confused! Thank you!

```
import SwiftUI
import Contentful
import Combine

let client = Client(spaceId: "qqq2yu4vbtpl", environmentId: "master", accessToken: "LurTiklxcr0ARTpI9z7GVTz-mjMO6OFVsoSZ8V7GJ4c")
//let client = Client(spaceId: "0ge8xzmnbp2c", accessToken: "03010b0d79abcb655ca3fda453f2f493b5472e0aaa53664bc7dea5ef4fce2676")

func getArray(id: String, completion: @escaping([Entry]) -> ()) {
    let query = Query.where(contentTypeId: id)
    
    client.fetchArray(of: Entry.self, matching: query) { result in
        switch result {
        case .success(let array):
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion(array.items)
            }
        case .error(let error):
            print(error)
        }
        print(result)
    }
}

class CourseStore: ObservableObject {
    @Published var courses: [Course] = courseData
    
    init() {
        let colors = [#colorLiteral(red: 0.3635728061, green: 0, blue: 0.8927152753, alpha: 0.8470588235), #colorLiteral(red: 0.2461163998, green: 0.3063159585, blue: 1, alpha: 0.8470588235), #colorLiteral(red: 0.3414418995, green: 0.653152287, blue: 0.405282855, alpha: 0.8470588235), #colorLiteral(red: 0.8906980753, green: 0.684363246, blue: 0, alpha: 0.8470588235), #colorLiteral(red: 0.5725490451, green: 0, blue: 0.2313725501, alpha: 1), #colorLiteral(red: 0.5058823824, green: 0.3372549117, blue: 0.06666667014, alpha: 1), #colorLiteral(red: 0.1411764771, green: 0.3960784376, blue: 0.5647059083, alpha: 1), #colorLiteral(red: 0.5568627715, green: 0.3529411852, blue: 0.9686274529, alpha: 1), #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)]
        
        getArray(id: "course") { (items) in
            items.forEach { (item) in
                self.courses.append(Course(
                    title: item.fields["title"] as! String,
                    subtitle: item.fields["subtitle"] as! String,
                    image: item.fields["image"] as! String,
                    logo: item.fields["logo"] as! String,
                    color: colors.randomElement()!,
                    show: false))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For my Data.swift file, I have written the following code fyi:

```
import SwiftUI

struct Post: Codable, Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var title : String
    var body : String
    
}

class API {
    func getPosts(completion: @escaping ([Post]) -> ()) {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts") else { return }
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, _, _) in
            guard let data = data else { return }
            
            let posts = try! JSONDecoder().decode([Post].self, from: data)
            
            // Must be async to run API call
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion(posts)
            }
        }
        .resume()
    }
}
```

And here is the code for my DataStore.swift, think it will be helpful for my data fetching script:

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class DataStore: ObservableObject {
    @Published var posts: [Post] = []
    
    init() {
        getPosts()
    }
    
    func getPosts() {
        API().getPosts { (posts) in
            self.posts = posts
        }
    }
}
```